# How to implement react-native-siri-shortcut properly?

Tags: react-native, siri, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to use Siri Shortcuts in a react-native app I am developing. I am using react-native-siri-shortcuts and I have it allowing me to donate shortcuts and suggest shortcuts. If I then go to the shortcuts app and add it, I am able to use Siri and the shortcut. I can even use the shortcut to print different stuff to the phone screen or put in data to my apps database.

I am running into an issue with getting Siri to speak. If I want Siri to fetch data and then say a string to the User can I do that in React Native or do I need to use swift to do this?

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm also facing similar problem, were you able to achieve it ?